# chrome.downloads download a folder with multiple urls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

Hello I am trying to build a chrome extension for downloading multiple images in **folder**.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( (request, sender, sendResponse ) => {
if ( request.action === "download") {
    for (let i = 0; i < request.data.length; i++) {
        chrome.downloads.download({url: request.data[i].src})
    }
    sendResponse("Done")
   }
 })
```

this downloads every URL separately. my goal is to have the user download **one** **folder** with all URL's

Comment: What you want to know is how can the extension create a folder under the downloads folder and change it to the default downloads folder?

Comment: Use `filename` parameter like 'foo/' + namePortionOfEachUrl

Comment: @NorioYamamoto no I want the user to download a folder that's containing each and every URL, currently each URL is downloaded separately and you get about  80 URLs in the Downloads folder

Comment: Is it that your loop triggers the file chooser (so the user can select a location) on every iteration of the loop? If that's true, I'm guessing you want the chooser to only appear one time and put all the files in the same location. Have I got this right?